# Address used on Binance lost, and no funds in wallet

Tags: wallet

I have created an Iota wallet address. I sent Iota from Binance, but after a few hours I logged in and the address was gone and no funds were showing in wallet. The address I sent funds to isn't showing on accous/transaction.

How do I claim my address with seed and send it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check to see if Binance approved the withdraw? Also what is the address that you withdrew to? Make sure this isn't your seed but the address which is found under the "Receive" tab on the wallet

Comment: Binance aproved it, at least it say so on their page, on tangle explorer it says that addres have xx amount miotas  i just cant get addres back to iota wallet i even updated wallet to x.x.6 lateset ver made 20+ generated addreses

Comment: What do you mean can't get address back to iota wallet? Once you receive IOTA to your address it automatically generates another address for you. What is the address you withdrew to?

Comment: OMFQSDJCGJ9FUDKKFXFOBRNS9OKDDSFEEJYJSEUAVOJTZYKAWCTUTBWEBIFOZCSHQUFIEQCYEVKK9WIMCKPGWXBJUX
   address

Comment: NFAUGQETGVYGKYEPGYZASBYEJCJXVOBQJHBWH9UWRSVB9TBBBLMOOZYYETBSZ9G9SFFRTWPCOHILZ9999      txid

Comment: IN MY IOTA WALLET THERE IS NO ADDRESS IN HISTORY, THERE ARE OTHERS BUT NOT THAT I SEND IT TO, AND MY BALANCE IS 0 ALL THE TIME